# how to add a "Search" section to People And Groups?

Tags: permissions, people-picker, people-search

When you want to give permissions , you go to **Site Settings >> People and Groups**.. And you will see the groups. But there is no search section. When we want to  search a group , we are getting group by name. But how can we add a search panel to find what we search in website?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in sharepoint to search something in peoples and groups, you have a option to search a user or group to check whether they exist in sharepoint and what permission they has. by using site setting -> under Users and permissions -> Site Permissions -> on ribbon you can see check permissions.

If you want, you can perform this action using powershell.